# Sharing oAuth Access Token in SDK

Tags: oauth, architecture, sdk, oauth-2.0

I'm creating an SDK which provides features that the official app uses. I want to enable oAuth login like Facebook. If a user signs up with Facebook in the official app, how can I have them log in to the same account from via the SDK that is integrated in another app?

Would I share the same access token across the SDK to all clients that implement it? Or is there a way to be able to allow the user to sign in via oAuth into an account that they created through the official app? My current thought is that we pull some ID (e.g. email address) and do a lookup to see if that email address exists in our database and work from there (which could be a pain if the user changes their email address).

Thank you